# Create Multiple Instances of ViewModel in RecyclerView

Tags: android, mvvm

I am creating a `ViewModel` inside the `onBindViewHolder` of a `recyclerView`; however, despite creating a new instance of the `ViewModel` the same `ViewModel` is being used. Here is what it looks like:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CatalogViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(componentData != null){
        holder.binding.setComponentData(componentData.get(position));
        holder.binding.setAdapter(adapter);
        CatalogAdapterViewModelFactory factory = new CatalogAdapterViewModelFactory(MyApp.getApplication(), componentData.get(position).getId());
        SliderViewModel sliderViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(fragment, factory).get(SliderViewModel.class);

        sliderViewModel.getPayloadListObservable().observe(fragment, new Observer<SliderData>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(SliderData payloads) {
                adapter.updateAdapterInfo(payloads.getPayload());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I create a new instance of `ViewModel` in the same fragment/view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewModel`s are associated with an owner, in this case the `Fragment`. As long as you pass the same `Fragment` to the factory method, you'll get the same viewmodel.

You should not use a `ViewModel` from the arch components for this use, you have to instantiate it manually each time.

Your problem is this line

```
SliderViewModel sliderViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(fragment, factory).get(SliderViewModel.class);
```

You need somethign like this

```
SliderViewModel sliderViewmodel = new SliderViewModel( /* pass stuff here */)
```